# Why I got an error in SQL syntax, Failed to insert record into MySQL table 1064 (42000)?

Tags: python, mysql

I want to create sentiment analysis using Vader in Python and Mysql. The problem is, I got the error on mysql, especially when to insert the data into the database. The error that I got is Failed to insert record into MySQL table 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '['compound'],'negative')' at line 2. Here are the code:

```
    sql_select_Query = "select a from table1 union select b from table1"
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
    records = cursor.fetchall()


    for row in records:
        print(row)

        sid_obj = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer() 

        sentiment_dict = sid_obj.polarity_scores(row) 

        if sentiment_dict['compound'] >= 0.05 : 
            sentiment = 'positive'

        elif sentiment_dict['compound'] <= - 0.05 : 
            sentiment = 'negative'

        else : 
            sentiment = 'neutral'

        mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO sent (q,polarity,senti) VALUES (%s,%s,%s) """

        records_to_insert = [(row,sentiment_dict['compound'], sentiment)]

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.executemany(mySql_insert_query, records_to_insert)
        connection.commit()
        print(cursor.rowcount, "Record inserted successfully into table")

except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print("Failed to insert record into MySQL table {}".format(error))


except Error as e:
    print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
finally:
    if  (connection.is_connected()):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
```

Database table:
[image]

Comment: In `VALUES (%s,positive')`, there's a missing open quote on `positive`, and also only two values but the `INTO` tuple wants three.

Comment: Yes, I already edit the code, but still got error on 'sentiment_dict['compound']'. It cannot insert into database. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO sent (q,polarity,senti) 
    VALUES (%s,sentiment_dict['compound'],'negative') """
```

This says you are trying to insert the string `sentiment_dict['compound']`, not the value it holds, into the database, which is most likely wrong. You probably want something like this (and similar for the other queries):

```
mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO sent (q,polarity,senti) 
    VALUES (%s,%s,'negative') """

# then later

records_to_insert = [(row, sentiment_dict['compound'])]
```

Or better, refactor to:

```
if sentiment_dict['compound'] >= 0.05 : 
    sentiment = 'positive'
elif sentiment_dict['compound'] <= - 0.05 : 
    sentiment = 'negative'
else: 
    sentiment = 'neutral'

mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO sent (q,polarity,senti) 
    VALUES (%s,%s,%s) """

records_to_insert = [(row, sentiment_dict['compound'], sentiment)]
```

(BTW, `cursor.executemany()` seems unnecessary since you only ever use a single set of values at a time, although I suspect you are debugging the simple case first.)

Comment: I have tried your second method(refactor), but got another error, which is 'Python type tuple cannot be converted'. What's the problem actually? The polarity is in decimal number (ex:0.5678). Is it this cause the problem?

Comment: No, the `%s` are placeholders, not actual string requests. I'm not sure what the problem could be; can you [edit] into the main question your database schema, please, just in case there is something there?

Comment: Already update the code. The latest error that I got is 'Failed to insert record into MySQL table Failed executing the operation; Python type tuple cannot be converted'

Comment: `polarity` is declared as `int(100)` (100??) but we are passing in a float, which might be why there is a conversion problem?

Comment: I already changed it to decimal (6,4). But, still not working. Im not sure if it is conversion problem or others